# Htaccess rewrite if filename contains specific suffix

Tags: image, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I'd like to rewrite every image (png|webp|jpeg) with the name `filename-tn.xyz` to `filename-200x200.xyz`. How do I replace this variable without changing the rest of the url?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. It should rename any `png`, `jpeg` and `webp`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)-tn\.(png|jpeg|webp)$    /$1-200X200.$2 [R,L]
```

EDIT:
This will rename the image, but keep the old name in the url bar.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)-tn\.(png|jpeg|webp)$    /$1-200X200.$2 [L]
```

Comment: Okay. Works great. Is there a possibility to just display the other image without redirecting? But else this great already, thanks!

Comment: Yup, check my edit. I removed the `R` which told it to redirect to the new link.

Comment: Thank you very much!! One last question: Does this influence SEO? It shouldn't, because the viewer doesn't "see" the change, does he?

Comment: It shouldn't have an effect on SEO, but because Google constantly changes its algorithm, there's no way to say for certain

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Since you answered some questions in the WP section, I assume you have some knowledge about WP.

Do you know a way to change the naming scheme of thumbnails in WP?

Comment: I don't think you can, but I'm still relatively new to WP so starting a new question might get you better answers.